# How do I apply new documentation to legacy minified file?

Tags: javascript, webpack, jsdoc, legacy

I'm trying to apply new documentation to legacy code that is

- Undocumented
- Minified (We don't have the source code)
- Included in the rest of the code via `window.thing = thing` in the minified file, instead of using modules and exports.
- Used literally everywhere.  It's the base framework for the entire web application.

My main intent is to get vsCode to display some intellisense for this module when I create a new page/file, rather than having to copy&paste code from other pages/files before it will tell me how to use the module's methods.  And even then, it doesn't tell me how it works.  Although after a few months I can now write this code somewhat reliably without looking, I've had to unravel the minified file some to find all the methods and properties available.  I should be copy&pasting imports, not the whole damn file.  We're also bringing in new developers soon, and (although coworkers disagree), I want to have something more for them to look at then just 'follow the pattern on the other pages'.

We are using webpack and have the ability to use modules.  I prefer the module pattern, but it is clear that those who came before us did not.  Using window.thing to use the module between files.  My coworkers prefer to 'follow the pattern already there', rather than trying to fix old code.  I don't whole-heartedly disagree, but still.  So I need to make this as unobtrusive as possible.

webapp/documentation/main.js

```js
import './thing.js';

/**@type {thing}**/
var thing; // This does not work. `thing` is marked as any.
           // So I changed the type to thingModule.

/**@type {thingModule}**/
var thing; // This works.

/**@type {thingModule}*/
window.thing; // This does not work.

/**@type {thingModule}**/
var thing = window.thing; // Works for thing
    // But does not change window.thing
```

However, none of those above propagate into the next file.

webapp/view/someFile.js

```js
import '../../documentation/main.js';
/**@type {thingModule}**/ var thing = window.thing;

// Cannot change below this line //
thing.addView(/*blah blah blah*/);
thing.doStuff();
```

This allows me to look up properties of *thing*.  But it does change the code slightly.  Not much, but just enough that it would be frowned upon if left in the code when committed.  Plus, if I find other modules that need similar documentation, I don't want a growing import statement for just documentation.
I need to be able to include it in a single line that only provides documentation.

```js
import '../../documentation/main.js';

// Cannot change below this line //
thing.addView(/*blah blah blah*/);
thing.doStuff();
```

In this case, *thing* is shown as ':any' instead of ':thingModule' like it needs to be.

tl;dr:
I need to assign the @typedef to window.thing and make the jsDoc definition propagate anywhere documentation is imported.  And I need to not change the actual declaration of `window.thing`.